# Symfony not trusting CloudFront/ALB proxy

Tags: symfony, amazon-cloudfront

When I call `$request->getClientIp();` I'm getting an AWS IP address. My app is behind CloudFront & an ALB.

I've set `framework.trusted_proxies` to `'127.0.0.1,REMOTE_ADDR'` as per https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment/proxies.html#but-what-if-the-ip-of-my-reverse-proxy-changes-constantly

App is running on Fargate (ECS)

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What service is your app running on? ECS, EKS, EC2?

Comment: @sytech - It's running on ECS (Fargate)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the fact that you are using both CloudFront and ALB.

In the [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment/proxies.html#but-what-if-the-ip-of-my-reverse-proxy-changes-constantly) is highlighted that (and I quote) "You also need to append the IP addresses or ranges of any additional proxy (e.g. CloudFront IP ranges) to the array of trusted proxies.". This is not only true when you use ELB and CloudFront but it is also the case for ALB.

Adding the [IP ranges](https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json) in your `trusted_proxies` parameter should resolve the issue.

As a final note: you don't need to add all the IPs but only the ones related to the service you are using.